# string datatype in c

Tags: c, string, char

I am beginner in C,
I am trying to write a function to return a string.
I know that in C we don't have string data type. instead of these I try to use an array of chars but It's not my solution.

```
char[] my_function(int x){
    if(x>0)
        return 'greaterThanZero';
    else
        return 'smallerOrEqualOfZero';
}
```

please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void my_function(int x, char **ret){
    if(x>0)
        *ret= "greaterThanZero";
    else
        *ret= "smallerOrEqualOfZero";
}
```

and in the main

```
int main() {
   char *string;
   my_function(1, &string);
   printf("%s",string);
}
```

Another way:

```
void my_function(int x, char *T){
        if(x>0)
            strcpy(T,"greaterThanZero");
        else
            strcpy(T, "smallerOrEqualOfZero");
    }
```

and in the main

```
int main() {
   char string[100];
   my_function(1, string);
   printf("%s",string);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The return type needs to be `const char *` and the string literals need to be enclosed in double quotes:

```
const char * my_function(int x)
{
    if (x > 0)
        return "greaterThanZero";
    else
        return "lessThanOrEqualToZero";
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("my_function(1)  = %s\n", my_function(1));
    printf("my_function(0)  = %s\n", my_function(0));
    printf("my_function(-1) = %s\n", my_function(-1));
    return 0;
}
```

Note that single quotes are used for `char` variables:

```
char c = 'X';                // single character - single quotes
char *s = "Hello world!";    // string - double quotes
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `"` instead of `'` (`'greaterThanZero'` should be `"greaterThanZero"`)

Answer (score -1):

Use double quotes around greaterThanZero & smallerOrEqualOfZero.

Alternately, you can also return a single character (say g/s) & then use condition in the caller function.

NOTE: "greaterThanZero" will generally go onto the const section, not on stack. Hence it should be safe to return from function.